# IC part number used for wrist strap ESD monitoring

Tags: identification, components, esd

Can somebody help to check the part number for this IC from its marking? This IC is used in an ESD monitoring device.

[image]

[image]

I tried to google "IC 6017808", but no results.

Comment: i just found this in Aliexpress, cannot provide better picture, for the title already change

Comment: the logo looks like ST Microelectronics

Comment: Yes correct, can you help me to check this one ?

Comment: why do you want this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like an St LM324. You’ll have to chase out the circuit a bit to be sure.
[image: datasheret pinout]

Comment: Yes, you're correct

Comment: @RizkisWalker thanks for following up. Can you mark this answer as correct then?